# All my plots in Rstudio just show up as gray boxes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot and geoms to show my data, but the plot sidebar area just shows a gray box with the `x` and `y` axis correctly labeled.

Here is the output image:

[image: gray plot area]

The code which made the plot:

```
ggplot(Wc, aes(y = popsafe, x = rnground)) +
   geom_jitter(aes(col = me)) +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, col = "black")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's very difficult to help, since we have no data to test with. Please read one of: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and/or (perhaps most helpful) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, then come back and edit your question.

Comment: You're missing a `geom_point(...)` or `geom_line(...)` in your `ggplot` command to actually draw the data.

Comment: This typically happens when you use `ggplot()` without an associated geom, as @MauritsEvers suggested, so I don't know that your example code leads to your example output.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Both `geom_jitter()` and `geom_smooth()` draw data.

Comment: @ClausWilke Yup, you're absolutely right. I just superficially screened for `geom_line` and `geom_point` and then drew the wrong conclusion. It seems you got to the bottom of things in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your dataset is empty. We don't know what your dataset contains, so here an example with the built-in `iris` dataset. First a proper plot, using the same geoms and mappings you use:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = Species)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, col = "black")
```

[image]

Now I remove all the data from the dataset and replot:

```
library(dplyr)
iris_empty <- filter(iris, Sepal.Length < 0)
ggplot(iris_empty, aes(y = Sepal.Length, x = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = Species)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, col = "black")
```

[image]

A simple `head(Wc)` would confirm whether your dataset actually contains any data.